# Express several commonly used conditional statements

Tags: powershell, powershell-4.0

There are several common conditional statements that are often used, for example:

Whether it is contain, whether it starts with the letters, whether it ends with the letters, whether it is empty.

Can someone write the code in a unified way?

```
$var = "word somestring"
if ($var --Does not contain-- "somestring") {
    Write-Host "true"
}
```

```
$var="word somestring"
if ($var --Does not start with-- "somestring") {
    Write-Host "true"
}
```

```
$var = "word somestring"
if ($var --Does not Ends with-- "somestring") {
    Write-Host "true"
}
```

```
$var = "word somestring"
if ($var --Is Not Empty--) {
    Write-Host "true"
}
```

Comment: take a look at string methods - `.StartsWith()`, `EndsWith()`, and `.Contains()`. if you want a bit more speed, look into regex with `-match '^asdfg'`, `-match 'asdfg$'`, and `-match 'asdfg'`. for the `not empty`, use `-not [string]IsNullOrEmpty()`.

Comment: Thank you, I have no way to mark your answer, oha

Comment: $var -eq $null    use this to judge whether it is empty?

Comment: you are most welcome! no need to mark anything as an answer ... i doubt this basic stuff qualifies for an official answer status. [*grin*]

Comment: @Lee_Dailey you should post it as an answer; it most certainly qualifies. Also slight typo: `[string]::IsNullOrEmpty()`, but do note that method will also return true if the string is `$null`, not just "empty". A simpler way to compare for both might be to just let the string coalesce to bool, as in `if ($string)` or `if (-not $string)`. For a true empty test, maybe comparing to `[string]::Empty` is better, or just `if ($string.Length)`, with the caveat that [some strings might have length 0 without being empty](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/385906/3905079) (untested).

Comment: @Lee_Dailey Yes, please post it as answer. Otherwise, this question will remain 'Unanswered' for years to come ;)

Comment: @Lee_Dailey String methods provide better performance than regular expression matches (~20% in a quick benchmark), so they should be preferred for speed, unless multiple string comparisons can be merged into a single regex match.

Comment: @tianyi Are you looking for separate expressions for either of your use cases, or are you looking for a canonical expression that covers all of them combined?

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - ah! i was thinking of tests i ran several years ago ... and you are correct that they were fairly complex sets of tests. thank you for the info! [*grin*]

Comment: @briantist - submitted ... thanks for the feedback! i had forgotten about `[string]::Empty` ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$var = "word somestring"

# $var --Does not contain-- "somestring"
if ($var -notmatch "somestring") {
    Write-Host "true"
}

# $var --Does not start with-- "somestring"
if ($var -notmatch "^somestring") {
    Write-Host "true"
}

# $var --Does not start with-- "somestring"  - case sensitive
if (-not $var.StartsWith("somestring")) {
    Write-Host "true"
}

# $var --Does not Ends with-- "somestring"
if ($var -notmatch "somestring`$") {
    Write-Host "true"
}

# $var --Does not Ends with-- "somestring"  - case sensitive
if (-not $var.EndsWith("somestring")) {
    Write-Host "true"
}

# $var --Is Not Empty--
if (-not [String]::IsNullOrEmpty($var)) {
    Write-Host "true"
}
```

Please note: The string (say .Net) methods are case sensitive by default, where PowerShell is case insensitive.

Comment: You can use -cnotmatch for case sensitive.

Answer (score 2):

what you want are the string methods OR regex & the `-match` operator. [*grin*]

here one way to see the methods ...

```
'asdf' |
    Get-Member -MemberType Methods
```

here's one way to see the static methods of the `[string]` type ...

```
'asdf' |
    Get-Member -Static
```

for regex, i recommend regex101.com ... [*grin*]

here's some demo code for the ideas involved ...

```
$StringList = @(
    'qwerty is at the start of this string'
    'at the string-end, is qwerty'
    'in the middle, qwerty is placed'
    'the target word is not in this string'
    # below is an empty string
    ''
    )
$Target = 'qwerty'

foreach ($SL_Item in $StringList)
    {
    '+' * 50
    '--- Current test string   = "{0}"' -f $SL_Item
    '=== String Methods ==='
    'Target at start           = {0}' -f $SL_Item.StartsWith($Target)
    'Target at end             = {0}' -f $SL_Item.EndsWith($Target)
    'Target anywhere in string = {0}' -f $SL_Item.Contains($Target)
    ''
    '=== Regex ==='
    'Target at start           = {0}' -f ($SL_Item -match "^$Target")
    'Target at end             = {0}' -f ($SL_Item -match "$Target$")
    'Target anywhere in string = {0}' -f ($SL_Item -match $Target)
    ''
    '=== Empty ==='
    'String is $Null or empty  = {0}' -f [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($SL_Item)
    'String is $Null or empty  = {0}' -f ([string]::Empty -eq $SL_Item)
    ''
    }
```

truncated output ...

```
++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
--- Current test string   = "qwerty is at the start of this string"
=== String Methods ===
Target at start           = True
Target at end             = False
Target anywhere in string = True

=== Regex ===
Target at start           = True
Target at end             = False
Target anywhere in string = True

=== Empty ===
String is $Null or empty  = False
String is $Null or empty  = False

[*...snip...*] 

++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++
--- Current test string   = ""
=== String Methods ===
Target at start           = False
Target at end             = False
Target anywhere in string = False

=== Regex ===
Target at start           = False
Target at end             = False
Target anywhere in string = False

=== Empty ===
String is $Null or empty  = True
String is $Null or empty  = True
```

Comment: @tianyi - you are most welcome! glad to have helped a tad ... [*grin*]

Answer (score 1):

Here's a switch version of answer 2.  (switch also has a -regex option)

```
$StringList = 'qwerty is at the start of this string', 
  'at the string-end, is qwerty', 'in the middle, qwerty is placed', 
  'the target word is not in this string', ''

$Target = 'qwerty'

switch -wildcard ($StringList) {
  { $_.StartsWith($Target)      } { "'$target' at start of '$_'" }
  { $_.EndsWith($Target)        } { "'$target' at end of '$_'" }
  { $_.Contains($Target)        } { "'$target' anywhere in '$_'" }
  { $_ -match "^$Target"        } { "'$target' at start of '$_' (regex)" }
  { $_ -match "$Target$"        } { "'$target' at end of '$_' (regex)" }
  { $_ -match $Target           } { "'$target' anywhere in '$_' (regex)" }
  { [string]::IsNullOrEmpty($_) } { "'$target' not in IsNullOrEmpty() '$_'" }
  { ([string]::Empty -eq $_)    } { "'$target' not in ::Empty '$_'" }
  $target*                        { "'$target' start of '$_' (wildcard)" }
  *$target                        { "'$target' end of '$_' (wildcard)" }
  *$target*                       { "'$target' anywhere in '$_' (wildcard)" }
  ''                              { "'$target' not in empty '$_'" }
}


'qwerty' is at start of 'qwerty is at the start of this string'
'qwerty' is anywhere in 'qwerty is at the start of this string'
'qwerty' at start of 'qwerty is at the start of this string' (regex)
'qwerty' anywhere in 'qwerty is at the start of this string' (regex)
'qwerty' start of 'qwerty is at the start of this string' (wildcard)
'qwerty' anywhere in 'qwerty is at the start of this string' (wildcard)
'qwerty' is at end of 'at the string-end, is qwerty'
'qwerty' is anywhere in 'at the string-end, is qwerty'
'qwerty' is at end of 'at the string-end, is qwerty' (regex)
'qwerty' anywhere in 'at the string-end, is qwerty' (regex)
'qwerty' end of 'at the string-end, is qwerty' (wildcard)
'qwerty' anywhere in 'at the string-end, is qwerty' (wildcard)
'qwerty' is anywhere in 'in the middle, qwerty is placed'
'qwerty' anywhere in 'in the middle, qwerty is placed' (regex)
'qwerty' anywhere in 'in the middle, qwerty is placed' (wildcard)
'qwerty' not in IsNullOrEmpty() ''
'qwerty' not in ::Empty ''
'qwerty' not in empty ''
```